# Alguma traducão para Elbow Grease

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

Ultimamente tenho encontrado a expressão [*Elbow grease*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_grease), que é usada para trabalho manuais "extensivos", especialmente para esfregar/polir algo.

Existe alguma expressão equivalente (e tão geral) no português?

Um exemplo seria:

> "After some elbow grease, the old piece was shining like new".

Comment: Deixo como comentário porque não consegui encontrar nenhuma referência que corroborasse o que vou dizer, mas eu acho que "trabalho de cotovelo" é uma expressão que existe e significa isto.

Comment: De fato, nunca ouvi esta expressão (motivo da pergunta).

Comment: *Trabalho braçal* tem um significado muito próximo, talvez idêntico, mas me parece muito "séria" para ser um bom equivalente.

Comment: elbow grease é uma expressão idiomática muito comum: fazer um esforço caprichado para conseguir um bom resultado para tudo que sería trabalho manual.

Comment: @stafusa, de fato, estava pensando um algo mais descontraído, mas não devo encontrar uma expressão assim em PT. Vou ter que me contentar com o que encontrar, tal qual a resposta.

Comment: @Lambie, exato, mas ela tem um pouco de humor junto, coisa que fica dificil na traducão de *trabalho manual*.

Comment: @Guto Trabalho manual não está no trecho. Elbow grease não tem humor.  Depois de esfregar bem o/a [x], ficou novinho/novinha. Se usar novinho/ha, dá o mesmo tom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso a tradução literal para "elbow grease" (trabalho braçal, ou trabalho de cotovelo) resulta em uma expressão  que não me parece ser usada cá por estas bandas. O termo mais usado seria **"polimento"** e, no caso, **"um polimento caprichado"** já que em Inglês existe o termo "polishing up" para um polimento comum. Certamente, dependendo do objeto da ação, poderá ser também **"uma boa esfrega"**.

> - [**elbow grease**](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=elbow+grease&rlz=1C1ARAB_enBR495BR495&oq=elbow+grease&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3054j1j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)  -  hard physical work, especially vigorous polishing or cleaning.